# Two neutrals and two Commons in the same box. Attempting a new switch

Tags: switch, neutral

Remodeling and reinstalling light fixtures in an old room of an old house.

There is only one light switch

That single light switch activates a fan on one side of the room and a separate light on the other side of the room

When I opened the switch box there were two white wires tied together and two black wires connected to the switch with the ground.

I have a new switch that has two switches in one switch unit.

I am unaware how to wire it correctly so that each independent switch will activate each independent fixture in the room.

Since both black wires were hooked up to the initial switch I just repeated that on the new switch.

This just does the same thing however where one switch activates both light fixtures.

If I rewire it in a different configuration all that happens is I get the second switch to do the same thing.

Is this not even a possibility? Is everything have to be completely rewired?

[image]

Comment: Waitaminute! There's a black and a gold screw on that switch. That's _NOT_ a normal, SPST switch. Please show us a picture of the front of the switch _and_ the other side of the switch. Also, is this the original wiring or a pic of your new wiring.

Answer (score 5):

> When I opened the switch box there were two white wires tied together and two black wires connected to the switch with the ground.

That's completely normal switch wiring.  The neutral is not switched by the switch and simply passes through.  The switch interrupts the hot wire so you can turn the light off.  Basic "power at the switch" arrangement.

> I have a new switch that has two switches in one switch unit.

Not going to work. You only have one thing to switch.

> Is this not even a possibility? Is everything have to be completely rewired?

That's correct. As things are now, the wiring from this switch only goes to one of the devices. The second device takes its power from the first one.   The only way to correct that would be to bust into the walls and run /3+ground cable from this switch to wherever the /2+gnd cable goes now.

There are unsafe ways to get it to work, but they involve energizing the ground wire, which destroys the safety value of having it.  I won't discuss them except to warn you off from them.

Answer (score 2):

One black is the hot, brings power to the switch.

The second black is a switch hot that goes to the light or fan.

At the light or fan is a second cable supplying power to the other from the switched hot.

The easiest way to have the light switched separately from the fan, is to change the light fixture to one with a pull chain switch or a smart bulb.